# Show the full content of evernote notes (with applied styles, colors, pictures, not only the text)

Tags: python, django, evernote

Show the full content of evernote notes (with applied styles, colors, pictures, not only the text).
I would like to start from showing the stylized text and the images:

> image/gif
>   image/jpeg
>   image/png

After that I plan to render the another MIME types:

> application/pdf
>   audio/wav
>   audio/mpeg

I would like to get with Python Django something similar to this project, 
written with Node Js Express:
https://dngevernoteapp.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=86365386312514542865707&cm_mc_sid_undefined=1455035755

or
https://sandbox.evernote.com/

[image]

My attempts:

1)
views.py:

```
from fenml import ENMLToHTML
# the fenml.py is my internal fork of the 
# https://github.com/CarlLee/ENML_PY/blob/master/__init__.py 
# with slightly modified code. 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
....
title_contents[note.title] = html2text.html2text(BeautifulSoup(ENMLToHTML(content)).prettify())
```

callback.html:

```
<ul>
  {% for title, content in title_contents.items %}
    <li><b>{{ title }}</b><br>{{ content }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Output:

- **Dive Into Python (Mark Pilgrim)**
   otherwise it will return None. -
  Highlight Loc. 481-82 | Added on Tuesday, 4 December 12 06:42:31
  GMT+00:59

2)
views.py:

```
title_contents = {}
for note in result_list.notes:
    content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, 
                                        note_store.getNote(note.guid, 
                                        True,False, False, False).guid)
    title_contents[ note.title ] = BeautifulSoup(ENMLToHTML(content)).prettify()
return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks, 
                                                  'result_list': result_list, 
                                                  'title_contents': title_contents})
```

Output:

•

```
    ('\xef\xbb\xbfDive Into Python (Mark Pilgrim)', u'<html>\n <body>\n otherwise it will return None.\n <br/>\n <br/>\n <span style="color:grey;">\n - Highlight Loc. 481-82 | Added on Tuesday, 4 December 12 06:42:31 GMT+00:59\n </span>\n </body>\n</html>')
```

Comment: Link to your fork of ENML_PY ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're going to have to modify the ENML to HTML converter to deal with attachments with the mime types you care about. Eg, for images, replace the en-media with an img src="whateverTheSourceShouldBe.jpg". Other mime types will be more complicated - eg for pdfs, you could use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render the pdf, but that means you're going to have to attache to an element after the initial render. i.e., spit it out to the DOM with a unique identifier (eg div id="foo-pdf-somethingelse") and then attach to it via pdf.js.